# Gumstix device tree and SPI

Tags: linux, spi, device-tree, gumstix

I am attempting to upgrade to a more recent kernel, so I've grabbed the yocto build from https://github.com/gumstix/yocto-manifest and built that. That image successfully boots my unit, so that is a good first step. I had to enable the SPIDEV driver in the kernel, and that part worked.

My board is based on a gumstix Tobi board, and that's what device tree my u-boot loads at boot time. However, I cannot seem to get SPI to work. I have added the following to the file omap3-overo-storm-tobi.dts file:

```
&omap3_pmx_core {
        mcspi1_pins: pinmux_mcspi1_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                        OMAP3_CORE1_IOPAD(0x21c8, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE0)        /* mcspi1_clk.mcspi1_clk */
                        OMAP3_CORE1_IOPAD(0x21ca, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE0)       /* mcspi1_simo.mcspi1_simo */
                        OMAP3_CORE1_IOPAD(0x21cc, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE0)        /* mcspi1_somi.mcspi1_somi */
                        OMAP3_CORE1_IOPAD(0x21ce, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE0)       /* mcspi1_cs0.mcspi1_cs0 */
                        OMAP3_CORE1_IOPAD(0x21d0, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE0)       /* mcspi1_cs1.mcspi1_cs1 */
                >;
        };

};

&mcspi1 {
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&mcspi1_pins>;

        spidev@0 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                spi-max-frequency = <48000000>;
                reg = <1>;
                spi-cpha;
        };

};
```

Upon a reboot this has successfully created a /dev/spidev1.1 device, but if I attempt to send anything to it I do not see the clock lines or the CS1 line go active. I feel like I'm missing a piece here, but I'm unsure where to go. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: (1) Always review the kernel syslog for relevant messages.  (2) Reconfigure the kernel, and enable the SPI debug capability (also requires CONFIG_KERNEL_DEBUG).

Comment: `PIN_INPUT` for output pins?!